# Theorem on signs of eigenvalues of $Q$ and eigenvalues of $A^T Q A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a square symmetric matrix $Q$ and an invertible matrix $A$, there is a theorem that states the matrices $Q$ and $A^T Q A$ have the same number of positive eigenvalues and the same number of negative eigenvalues and the same number of zero eigenvalues.  What is the name of this theorem (who is it by?), and could you prove it or provide a link to a proof of it.

Comment: The same number of zero eigenvalues should be obvious, just looking at the rank.

Comment: [Sylvester's law of intertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

Comment: Yes, thank you @user1551, it think that's what I am looking for.